# Best practice for processing event posts

Tags: sonos

What is the best practice for processing event posts from Sonos ? Should one respond with a 200 and then validate the event signature and handle if valid, or validate the signature and respond with 200 if valid ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I decided to always return 200 I.e. I did receive the event post even though I have not checked the signature yet. In the callback, I validate the signature and if it is Ok I send the headers and the event data to my app.